# Problems with adding favicon icon

Tags: favicon

I am trying to add a favicon to a website. Added the shortcut icon ref and href to the image location. But I still can't see the favicon image on the tabs.

`<link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="images/ico.ico">`

I have tried to reload and refresh index page. Just to see that it works but no favicon appears on the tab. Can someone please help me?

Comment: Show us the relevant code in the page that's not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to put `link` attribute directly inside `head` tag, not inside `style` tag, as currently on website

Comment: I am a dunce. Total novice at this but that works. Thanks a lot - was killing me.